# XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/@kolkov/angular-editor

Tags: angular, npm, http-status-code-404

I installed "**@kolkov/angular-editor**" using "**npm install @kolkov/angular-editor --save**".

### app.module.ts

```
import { AngularEditorModule } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';

@NgModule({
    imports:        [AngularEditorModule]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

but when i run my application using **npm start** i am getting following error

**XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/@kolkov/angular-editor**

folder structure of node module is as follows:

[image]

please anyone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: it can be used as a component in template,  https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor#getting-started

Comment: @Vadi i followed the same link you mentioned but ended up which above problem.